# Why the result is different when I get value from a same pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Node {
    int a;
};

struct Node* prepare() {
    struct Node node = { 123456 };
    return &node;
}

int main() {
    struct Node* node = prepare();
    printf("%d\n", node->a);
    printf("%d\n", node->a);
    return 0;
}
```

following is the result

[image]

so why the results are different?

Comment: Local variables are no longer valid once the function exits. Using the address of such a variable outside the function is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Any decent compiler should be able to detect this problem and issue a warning. If you don't get any warning, then please increase warning levels.

Answer (score 0):

`prepare` is returning a pointer to memory block, a local variable allocated on the stack. The memory block is reused by the system after return. When you print it the second time the memory block have been overwritten.

Comment: thanks , I know it but I forgot the principle in this code, when I understand and I realized how simple the question I ask.